# Propagating settings to multiple views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here's my my dilemma:

1. I have a main view. It has a Settings.cs class that grabs data from a SQL Server
2. I have many (10+) subviews, some of which have subviews on them.
3. Right now, I'm passing the Settings object from my main view down to each individual view

My question might be a little bit more "best practice", but shouldn't my ViewModels be relatively independent of the main view? Or is it OK to pass all settings data down to each view, even though each view will only use a small portion of it?

I wanted to make a setup where each viewmodel will call for its own settings class/data, but if I have a window (presumably a settings window that would change settings), how to I update the viewmodel with the updated settings if they are different instances of classes?

I've done static in the past, but that causes tight coupling, and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: What kind of settings?

Answer (score 0):

It is considered that each VM has its own data which is generally the accepted practice because it makes sense to keep data localized to where it is needed. But as the data needs expand if a VM needs access to data, then that access needs to be provided. If you want to design a system of access that is up to you.

I have worked on systems where either the main VM or specific settings objects are made available using statics on the app instance. Hence all access to needed data is globalized across the app.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to create a Settings class that takes care of serializing/deserializing all settings for the app. This class is either static or singleton and provides global thread safe access to the settings.
This class also exposes an event, "SettingsUpdated" that is raised whenever the settings are changed (usually this is triggered by calling serialize to save the updated settings).

Then the ViewModels can simply get the settings from this class. And if any of the ViewModels need to be notified of changes to the settings, they can subscribe to the "SettingsUpdated" event and read the updated settings.